# Checking equality/inequality of multiple variables

Tags: c++, if-statement

Let's say we have four variables: `int a, b, c, d;`. I need to check if excatly two of them are equal.

So for example: `1 1 9 5` is true, but `3 9 8 4` and `3 3 3 1` are false.

Of course writing an if statement for this would take a lot of time, won't be easily readable and it would be easy to make a mistake writing it.

What is the best way to write such statement?

Comment: What do you consider to be "best"?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm fastest and shortest way to do it I guess

Comment: The best way to write any code is the simplest, easiest way that meets the specified requirements.

Comment: @user4581301 excatly, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Then write the simplest way you can think of and time it. If it takes less than the required amount of time, you're done. If not, you move to the next most complicated, possibly skipping a few steps if you were way off the mark with the first one, solution.

Comment: just check if you have exactly 3 unique values with a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

One involves explicitly checking all the conditions. Since you have 4 variables, you only 6 conditions to check. These can easily be counted.

```
int n = (a == b) + (a == c) + (a == d) + (b == c) + (b == d) + (c == d);
```

Then check if `n` is 1. This works because a boolean value will be converted into an int (value 1 for true, 0 for false).

Another possibility is to store them all in a container (like a vector), sort it, then count the number of adjacent identical values.

Comment: actually, for `n=2` it finds the groups like `1 1 1 2` too. And for `n=1` it accepts groups like this: `1 1 2 2`.

Comment: @MartinYakuza for `1 1 1 2` `n` will be equal to 3 as `a == b` `b == c` and `a == c` all `true`

Comment: @Slava sorry, I read something wrong, it shows me `1 1 2 2` for `n=2` now.

Comment: and I think `n` needs to be 1 for it to work

Comment: @MartinYakuza I agree condition should be `n == 1`

Comment: "so n will have the number of variables that have the same value" not correct. For example if 4 have the same value then `n` is 6. If two have the same value then only one condition is true, ie `n = 1`

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ah, right. I've removed that statement.